# Ajax POST to another server - overcoming the cross domain restrictions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xss

Is the only proper way to achieve this by using a proxy? I'm working on a clicktail clone (web user interaction & mouse tracking analytics) and what I have so far is a script that will track all the user interactions and will post them to my server and save to the database, but the issue is if this script is added to a client who will be on another domain, the Ajax post will fail due to the cross domain scripting restrictions.

from reading about this, there are some hacks, but im keen to avoid them. It seems that a proxy is the only way round this. But that in turn poses a larger issue for me as any client who wishes to use my clicktail clone will also have to setup a proxy in addition to added javascript on their. This will be straight forward for a webmaster with a PHP site, as I can provide the script and they just bang it on their server, but for .net sites, they would have to include that in their solution and recompile, maybe i could provide a dll, but even that would have to be referenced.

I have been reading about this `HTML 5 window.postMessage` -> and this jquery plugin http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/ this looks good, and I think ill be able to use it to playback the captured user interactions, using Iframes but It doesn't, (at least I cannot see how) resolve the issue with cross domain AJAX posting.
if you were in my situation, could you post your possible solution ?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that cross-domain POSTs are really possible in your situation.
Here [How do I send a cross-domain POST request via JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-I-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-JavaScript) discussed the availability to configure the receiving server with Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
After that you can do POST via jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://to.com/postHere.php',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: '{"some":"json"}',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var value = responseData.someKey;
    },
    error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('POST failed.');
    }
});
```

Good luck!