# Is it feasible to send media files(images/ video/ pdf etc...) from a server to another server through Html Fom?

Tags: php, forms, file-upload, upload

> the case is: how to upload file through an [Html Form](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html) in server A and the Uploaded files should be sent to Server B

I read answers related to this topic, but its allow you **only** to send data in a post method.

1. [HTML/PHP Post method to different server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065765/html-php-post-method-to-different-server)
2. [Ajax POST to another server - overcoming the cross domain restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920574/ajax-post-to-another-server-overcoming-the-cross-domain-restrictions)

some answers advice to use the [`ftp_fput()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-fput.php) function, which is risky because your credentials will be online and accessible. (you should use [`ftp_login ( resource $ftp_stream , string $username , string $password )`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-login.php))

Answer (score 1):

**1. Usage of ftp** (make sure to use an encrypted connection, not plain ftp) and scp, where you can use ssh public key authentication, which is equally safe as storing your mysql password, just make sure the credentials are not accessible. You will need any kind of authentication anyway (also for html/php)

**1a. Rsync + crontab**
Isn't it possible to use some kind of cronjob and rsync to do the task?

**2. To receieve  send a file with curl**

```
<?php

$url = 'http://target-server/accept.php';
//This needs to be the full path to the file you want to send.
$file = realpath('./sample.jpeg');

// the post fields.
// note the "@", to denote that the file path should be evaluated
$post = array(
    'extra_post_field' => '123456',
    'file_contents' => '@' . $file
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

// send the request & close the connection
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// result is the response, this can also be a json response for example
echo $result;

?>
```

**2b. Receive a file (note: this example needs a security/authentication layer)**

```
<?php

// make sure targetFolder is writable by the webserver
$targetFolder = '/your/uploaded/files/folder';
// This will be the target file
$targetFile = $targetFolder . basename($_FILES['file_contents']['name']);

// do your authentication + validation here
echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_contents']['tmp_name'], $targetFile)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
    echo "Something went wrong uploading the file";
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, that's really useful to understand what i should do, but the CEO wont accept to share the credentials through the internet even if it was encrypted. anyway i gave u +1 :)